# Postgres escape special characters PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I want to insert this inside my table in Postgres but I don't know how to escape the special characters. Also, my string is much longer than the one below but contains many such instances.

```
'<a href='http:\/\/%%code%%' target='_blank'>'
```

Comment: i think you need to change your datatype of your filed, now you need to add **text** as datatype instead of your right now datatype, so you can store html directly on database filed..

Comment: Are you using prepared statements? If so you don't need to do anything special. If not, **use prepared statements**.

Answer (score 2):

Please use  [pg_query_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) in any data going into a Postgresql database or a similar method that escapes the string correctly. Do not under any circumstances trust any encoding coming from a client ie a Browser.